# Javascript - remove <br> after a button

Tags: javascript, dom

In this code

```
button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
```

I am removing a `button`.
Is there a way to remove not only the `button` but also a `<br>` after it?
Something like:

```
button.parentNode.removeChild((button+"<br>"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
var parent = button.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(button.nextSibling);
parent.removeChild(button);
```

Or if you don't have to support IE8 and below, you can use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.nextElementSibling) instead (which wouldn't consider blank text nodes between the elements):

```
parent.removeChild(button.nextElementSibling);
```

This assumes that the `br` element really is the button's next sibling. If not, you have to find it first:

```
var br = button.nextSibling;
while (br.nodeName !== 'BR') {
  br = br.nextSibling;
}
```